# Android SDK for the command line?

Tags: android, android-layout, command-line-interface

Are there any tools for building a command-line version of an application from an Android application and its layout?  Your Android layout would presumably need additional information, but not necessarily that much.

Now most Android SDK features won't make sense from the command line, but many like network services do.  [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) could provide a starting point for non-graphical SDK elements.

Comment: What is a "command line application" as you use it here? If you mean what people normally consider a command-line application to be, how would it have a layout? How would you run it? What does Android-x86 have to do with any of this? Or is your "command line application" one that *builds* a regular Android app (e.g., Ant, Maven, Gradle)?

Comment: The NDK has semi-official functionality for building a command line executable - though with almost no access to android-level services, and there's no particularly clean way to deploy these to a device, nor a nice environment for average users to run them in.  You can however fire an Intent to get a service buried in a normal application to do something in the background for you.

Comment: There is nothing ambiguous about what I asked, CommonsWare. A "command-line [version of an] application" always means an application that did exactly the same thing but ran from the command-line.  Not sure why your asking about build stuff.  An ncurses application most certainly does have a "layout" in the naive sense, but an Android application's layout could also be interpreted to provide a menu drive command line application, either ncurses or not.

Comment: What is ambiguous is : Am I asking for a command line version that runs under glibc or or under Android?  I left that intentionally ambiguous because anything that translates Android layout to menus for a command-line tool would be quite interesting.